# Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm using `C` API of `MMPEG` and getting this message. So I added `time_base` to my stream

```
videoStream = avformat_new_stream(formatContext, codec);
videoStream->time_base = AVRational{1, fps};
```

and got rid of it in context

```
codecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
codecContext->width = width;
codecContext->height = height;
codecContext->gop_size = 10;
codecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
//codecContext->time_base = AVRational{1, fps};
codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
```

`avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL)` immediately breaks

WHY? Do I need to apply the value to both of them? I've duplicated values to both, and the message gone. But isn't it just **wrong**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `codecContext->time_base` value is mandatory and should not be skipped. Uncomment it and you should be fine. Also see the [code example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c#L158) that ffmpeg provided.

As to why both values are needed: `AVStream` and `AVCodecContext` are two different structures that may or may not be used together, depending on what your code needs to do. They both need a `time_base` so they both have them. You may call it one of the many peculiarities in the ffmpeg codebase.